# Can Kevin copy parts of his identity disc?

Tags: tron-legacy

Kevin Flynn is a creator and his [identity disc](https://tron.fandom.com/wiki/Kevin_Flynn%27s_Identity_Disc) contains the ability to leave the grid and enter the real world.

Before his son was paged and entered the grid, why didn't Flynn copy whatever data he wanted to another disc (including the data allowing him to leave and enter the real world), delete those same parts from the original, and leave with Quorra to enter the real world, and destroy Clu from the outside?

I haven't seen the first Tron, the animated series or read the novelization, but given Flynn is a creator, disc copying doesn't seem impossible for him.

He could have left his disc for Clu to find just to bother him even more before removing him from the outside.

Comment: Maybe he can copy his identity disc, but it wouldn't have mattered, the doorway back to the real world was closed. After the rebellion of Clu, he didn't have an opportunity to return to the doorway before it closed. After that, he was stuck in the Grid.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Okay, but when his son showed up, and the portal is open, why not do what I suggested and all 3 can leave?

Comment: @QueenSvetlana - I doubt it works just like a code wheel that Flynn could separate to something else; It's probably more like a fingerprint or ID that the portal recognizes, and something Clu could easily recognize as faked if he got his hands on it.

Comment: @Radhil - He could leave the original disk with the data on how to escape deleted because he would've made a copy onto another disk. Clu would have no idea about the copy, and would only find out about the deleted parts later on. By that time, it's too late. For Flynn copying should be easy, he created an entire virtual world after all.